# EM_GETTEXTEX - wrongly documented return value?

Tags: c, winapi, richedit

According to MSDN, `EM_GETTEXTEX` returns the following:

```
The return value is the number of TCHARs copied into the
output buffer, including the null terminator.
```

Now take a look at the following code:

```
GETTEXTLENGTHEX gtl;
GETTEXTEX gt;
int len;
TCHAR *buf;

memset(&gtl, 0, sizeof(GETTEXTLENGTHEX));
gtl.flags = GTL_DEFAULT;
gtl.codepage = 1200;

len = SendMessage(hEditWnd, EM_GETTEXTLENGTHEX, (WPARAM) &gtl, 0);

printf("LEN: %d\n", len);

buf = malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR));

memset(&gt, 0, sizeof(GETTEXTEX));
gt.cb = (len + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR);
gt.flags = GT_DEFAULT;
gt.codepage = 1200;

len = SendMessage(hEditWnd, EM_GETTEXTEX, (WPARAM) &gt, (LPARAM) buf);

printf("LEN: %d NULLCHECK: %d\n", len, buf[len]);
```

For a RichEdit control that contains the text `Hello`, this program outputs the following:

```
LEN: 5
LEN: 5 NULLCHECK: 0
```

This is confusing me because MSDN says that the count value retuned by `EM_GETTEXTEX` is supposed to include the null terminator, thus I'd expect 6 but instead I get 5.

Is this a documentation bug or am I doing something wrong here?

***EDIT***

Here is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<assemblyIdentity
   version="1.0.0.0"
   processorArchitecture="x86"
   name="ELIMINATED FOR PRIVACY REASONS"
   type="win32"
/>
<description>ELIMINATED FOR PRIVACY REASONS</description>
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
          <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"/>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
</trustInfo>
<dependency>
   <dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity
      type="win32"
      name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
      version="6.0.0.0"
      processorArchitecture="X86"
      publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
      language="*"
      />
   </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
</assembly>
```

And here is the `CreateWindowEx()` call:

```
hEditWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, L"RichEdit20W", L"",
WS_VSCROLL|WS_HSCROLL|ES_LEFT|ES_AUTOHSCROLL|ES_AUTOVSCROLL|
WS_CHILD|ES_MULTILINE|WS_BORDER,  
0,0,0,0, hWnd, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

Comment: So what can we do to get this corrected on MSDN?

Comment: There are a lot of RichEdit versions, we can't see your CreateWindowEx() call or your manifest.  File doc bugs at connect.microsoft.com

Comment: Added requested information to OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a [doc pull request](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/win32/pull/1316) that has been merged, so assume it was indeed a mistake and it should be fixed by now.