# RichEdit - WM_GETTEXTLENGTH and EM_SETSEL consider different new lines characters

Tags: c++, winapi, richedit

RichEdit has a strange behavior. The `WM_GETTEXTLENGTH` message considers the new line characters as two characters `\r\n`, while the `EM_SETSEL` and `EM_EXSETSEL` messages consider them as one character `\n`.

This creates confusion and lot of bad things, for example the below function does not work well:

```
void CutLastFiveChars(HWND hRichEdit) {

    // Get the current text length
    int textLength = (int)SendMessage(hRichEdit, WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 0, 0);

    // Calculate the starting position for the selection
    int startPos = textLength - 5;
    if (startPos < 0) {
        startPos = 0;  // Ensure startPos is within bounds
    }

    // Set the selection to the last 5 characters
    SendMessage(hRichEdit, EM_SETSEL, startPos, textLength);

    // Replace the selected text with an empty string
    SendMessage(hRichEdit, EM_REPLACESEL, TRUE, (LPARAM)"");
}
```

How can I fix this?

Or, is there a way to disable automatically converting `\n` characters into `\r\n`?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-gettextlengthex

Comment: For histerical reasons the line ending for RichEdit is a single linefeed,  not carriage return+line feed as is common in the winapi.  WM_GETTEXTLENGTH dutifully hides that distinction, giving you a value that assumes you'll use WM_GETTEXT or GetWindowText() to retrieve the text with proper line endings.  But not what you want here, send EM_GETTEXTLENGTHEX to get the actual length.

Comment: I tested with Riched20.dll and RICHEDIT_CLASS, result for me is 2 chars more for each line. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38441090/em-gettextex-wrongly-documented-return-value

Comment: Thanks Hans Passant, works with EM_GETTEXTLENGTHEX

Comment: There is still a problem with EM_EXSETSEL and EM_SETSEL because the counting is done as if the separation lines have only one character and in fact there are two.

Answer (score 1):

As @HansPassant pointed, `EM_GETTEXTLENGTHEX` gets the actual length with considering the new line characters as one character `\r` which is the same way as the `EM_SETSEL` and `EM_EXSETSEL` messages. While `WM_GETTEXTLENGTH` considers the new line characters as two characters `\r` `\n`.

You just need to use the `EM_SETSEL` and `EM_EXSETSEL` messages with `EM_GETTEXTLENGTHEX`.
Then if you want to select a number of characters strictly, you need some extra effort. For example, revise the first selection based on `EM_GETTEXTEX`.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Have you made any attempt to read the [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-gettextlength) carefully?

`WM_GETTEXTLENGTH` is used for getting a buffer allocation size.

> To obtain the exact length of the text, use the `WM_GETTEXT`, `LB_GETTEXT`, or `CB_GETLBTEXT` messages, or the `GetWindowText` function.

Comment: 1. The question is how to correctly get the length of the text, not the text.

2. You test yourself or only quote from documentation ?

3. Return for me is 2 chars more for each line, not "The return value is the length of the text in characters, not including the terminating null character.". Maybe in documentation is something wrong. I tested with Riched20.dll and RICHEDIT_CLASS